# mvc logout after back button it redirect to main page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

the problem is its not redirect to login page after logout back button press.
i read lot of thing and i try lot of solution as well.

the current scenario is as below.

in **Global.asax** file

i have added below code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml

I called

```
function logout()
{
    window.location.href = '/account/logout';
}
```

In accountController.cs

```
public ActionResult logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon(); // it will clear the session at the end of request
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();

    return RedirectToAction("login", "account");
}
```

while I press back button 
it calls `commonController`

```
[SessionAuthorize]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getMenu()
{
    masterReturn objmasterReturn = new masterReturn();

    var client = new RestClient(string.Format("{0}/userMenu/getMenu", applicationTitle));
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "bearer " + Session["accessToken"].ToString() + "");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    if (response.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")
    {
        objmasterReturn.success = "true";
        //var details = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        //dynamic item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<masterReturn>(response.Content);
        //objmasterReturn.objectVal = item.objectVal;
        objmasterReturn.objectVal = response.Content;
    }
    else
    {
        objmasterReturn.success = "false";
        objmasterReturn.error = "error in api call !!!";
    }

    return Json(objmasterReturn);
}
```

now in FilterConfig.cs file

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
    public class SessionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            return httpContext.Session["accessToken"] != null;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/logout");
        }
    }
}
```

now problem with below line

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/logout");
```

I tried with

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/account/login");
```

but it does not redirect to login page.

is there any other working option as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/logout");
```

use like this, i hope this will solve your problem...

```
 filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "You Controller Name" }, { "action", "ActionMethod Name" } });
```

Comment: are you using custom actionfilter for it?

Comment: i used auth 2.0 process